# Publish stream in github

Tags: github, plugins, publish

I'm starting working on a little TypeScript plugin that I will put into Github.

I use Gulp to build my project and I think I will add this plugins to npm & bower at begining.

In many project in Github, you can see this kind of "images"( example of boostrap ):

[image]

After some research, I didn't find a tutorial to add this "images" in my readme...

If someone have a tutorial :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found after looking in all link in my Github project

You just need to go in **Settings > Integrations & services**

After just click in **browse directory** button to get some services needed to your project.

It seems to be the same for npm and others..